# Is there JSR for DataSource deploy from war?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, deployment, glassfish

I'm trying to summarize solutions for DataSource deploy during war deploy.
To be honest, it's not so convenient to add this manually from console.

I can see, that for example JBoss have solution: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/375-jboss-as-7-deployable-datasources.html

For Tomcat also there is context.xml which can deal with that.

**Do you know if it's possible on GlassFish?**

**Is there JSR which will standarize this? May be in JEE7.**

Answer (score 2):

In Glassfish it is possible to define application scoped resources in a *glassfish-resources.xml* (formerly *sun-resources.xml*) file

From the [Glassfish application deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/index.html):

> An application-scoped resource is defined in the glassfish-resources.xml deployment descriptor file. This file is
>   placed in the META-INF directory of the module or application archive.
>   For web applications or modules, this file is placed in the WEB-INF
>   directory. If any submodule archives of an enterprise application
>   archive have their own glassfish-resources.xml files, the resource
>   definitions are scoped to those modules only.

An example configuration looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-connection-pool name="mysql_rootPool" ...>
    <property name="serverName" value="myServer"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
    ...
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/mydb" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

The resource definition is the same as in the *domain.xml* of your Glassfish domain. You can copy it from there.

Comment: There is a very good blog entry about this GlassFish feature that is a bit more instructive than the deployment guide:  https://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/application_scoped_resources_in_glassfish.